# Redirected to a bad URI with Mechanize raises an invalid URI error

Tags: ruby, uri, mechanize

I am trying to communicate with a badly designed web server, but still I want to deal with it. The thing is, when I submit my login form, it tries to embed messages inside the URI, which makes the URI library stop.

The server redirects me to

```
/path/ConvolutedNameForMenuPage.menu?name=bmenu.P_MainMnu&msg=WELCOME+<b>Welcome,+Jonathan+Allard,+to+our+poorly+designed+Administrative+Systems!<%2Fb>Dec+07,+201102%3A27+PM
```

That's right, it's trying to pass me unparsed HTML code inside the redirect URI, which I am supposed to request in order to get it back. Sheesh, standards!

And now the URI library, visibly passionately upset by such bad practice, exclaims

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): /path/ConvolutedNameForMenuPage.menu?name=bmenu.P_MainMnu&msg=WELCOME+<b>Welcome,+Jonathan+Allard,+to+our+poorly+designed+Administrative+Systems!<%2Fb>Dec+07,+201102%3A27+PM   from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1202:in `rescue in merge'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1199:in `merge'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.0.1/lib/mechanize/page/meta_refresh.rb:32:in `parse'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.0.1/lib/mechanize/page/meta_refresh.rb:41:in `from_node'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.0.1/lib/mechanize/page.rb:282:in `block in meta_refresh'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
from /home/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
```

I feel your pain, `URI` lib.

Now, how do I catch this, parse back the URI correctly (or just drop it altogether) and submit back as if nothing happened? Or is this a bug somewhere between URI and Mechanize?

Comment: Just put the request in a rescue block? Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: @pguardiario It doesn't get much more complicated than this. It's basically `uri.merge('<')` and I'm stuck in a redirect. Also, there's not much to rescue as the URI throws an error every time.

Comment: So you're calling uri.merge('<') directly? Why are you doing that? If you show the code we won't have to guess what you're talking about.

Comment: @pguardiario No, the server redirects me to a path containing a "<" and it  crashes URI

Comment: Maybe Mechanize#redirect_ok = false will help, I really can't offer anything else without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the code, I have found where the issue comes from.

As I explained in [#177](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/issues/177):

> in
>   [`/lib/mechanize/page/meta_refresh.rb:40`](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/page/meta_refresh.rb)
>
> ```
> class Mechanize::Page::MetaRefresh
>
> def self.parse content, base_uri
>   return unless content =~ CONTENT_REGEXP
>
>   delay, refresh_uri = $1, $3
>
>   dest = base_uri
>   dest += refresh_uri if refresh_uri     # Oops!
>
>   return delay, dest
> end
> ```
>
> The referenced line will raise `URI::InvalidURIError` if `refresh_uri`
>   contains illegal symbols (such as `<`). I don't quite know where the
>   sanitize should be done though.

The [`URI#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-merge) of my error log is hidden in the [`+=`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-2B) operator on the *oops* line, if you wondered.